# If $f\in C^1$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$ and $\nabla f$ is bounded on every compact subset of $\Omega$, can we extend $f$ to $\overline\Omega$?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, lipschitz-functions

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open. We know that if $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ and $\nabla f$ is bounded, then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (hence uniformly continuous) and hence $f$ has a unique continuous extension to $\overline\Omega$.

Now suppose we only that $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ and $\sup_{x\in K}\|\nabla f(x)\|<\infty$ for all compact $K\subseteq\Omega$. Is this enough to ensure the existence of a unique continuous extension of $f$ to $\overline\Omega$?

Comment: Your first paragraph is not correct without some assumption about $\Omega$ beyond mere boundedness.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Which assumption on $\Omega$ do you've got in mind?

Comment: If $\Omega \subset \mathbf R^2$ is given by $1 < r < 2$ and $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ (in polar coordinates) the function $f(r,\theta) = \theta$ cannot be extended to $\overline \Omega$.  You need some stronger relationship between the topological and measure-theoretic boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, no it's not. For example,
$$f : (0, 1) \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}.$$
This is continuously differentiable, and the derivative is bounded on each compact subset of $(0, 1)$, but no continuous extension is possible.

(Note that being continuously differentiable implies that the derivative is bounded on each compact subset of the interior of the domain, so functions on open sets were always going to be ripe for picking counterexamples.)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but as written in the title of the question, I intended to assume that $\Omega$ is bounded and open. But I guess your example with  $(0,\infty)$ replaced by $(0,1)$ still works. My actual goal was to understand why $u_t$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185531/47771) has an extension to $\overline\Omega$ (as it is being claimed in some lecture notes). Is there a reason why this works in that situation?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I'll change it nonetheless.